# How to fire events from inside the state machine in boost::msm?

Tags: c++, boost-msm

I am new to boost::msm and I cannot figure out how to fire an event from inside a state machine using the basic front end.

Let's say I have two orthogonal regions:

- The first one has states A1 and A2
- the second one has states B1 and B2
- The transition from B1 to B2 is triggered by an event `ev_B1ToB2`.

Now, what I am asking is how to fire an event `ev_B1ToB2` when transitioning from A1 to A2 so that it gets processed by the state machine.

Of course, what I am trying to implement is much more complex and I am actually trying to do that from a submachine and the event will only be processed by the parent machine. Hence, my second question:

When an event is fired within a submachine, does it gets processed at a higher hierarchy level if the submachine does not respond to this event?

Comment: please provide some code of what you already have